# Erro visual em Visual Studio / VS2010 projects no 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Tenho o windows instalado num mac com boot camp e aparece me o visual studio 2010 assim:

[image: Erro]

já tentei alterar resoluçao de ecra, tamanho de letra, atualizaçoes da placa,...
Nada resolveu.
Já instalei o VS 2013 que funciona na perfeiçao mas nao consigo importar os projetos do VS2010.
Ou de uma maneira ou de outra gostava de resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigado pelas imensas respostas mas já resolvi, se alguem tiver o mesmo proble aqui vai:
Instale o Windows 7 ou 8 (o 8.1 não tem esta opção),
nas definições de visualização ir a DPI e ativar a opção que diz, Usar DPIs como se fosse XP e baixar para 150 %
Fica a funcionar direito.